# Language evolution stats on Git and SVN repositories

Tags: graphs, git, subversion, statistics

I am looking for a program that could display the evolution of the programming languages used over time in a Git or SVN repository. The output could be like the following:

[image]

So far, I have tried:

1) [CLOC](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/): the output only shows the current language breakdown:

[image]

2) [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/): it generates many statistics like evolution of number of lines of code over time (took me 2 hours on the TortoiseSVN project with:

```
svn checkout http://tortoisesvn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ tortoisesvn-read-only
svn log --xml -v > svn.log'
cd c:\statsvn
java -jar statsvn.jar C:\temp\svn\tortoisesvn\svn.log C:\temp\svn\tortoisesvn
```

)

[image]

commit word tags:

[image]

a lot of user statistics and so on but not what I want.

Comment: What is wrong with the solutions you've found?  What exactly do you mean by "evolution of programming languages"?

Comment: @ATG I would think he means like in December 2012 the repo was 50% Python, 30% C++, 15% Batch Script and 5% other, December 2013 the repo was 45% Python, 40$ C++, 10% Batch Script and 5% Other - with graphical or text output

Comment: @ATG Did you see the first graph, right at the beginning of my question?  The solutions I've found don't allow to extract the data from a repository. I can add all StatSVN's output graphs but some might complain again about scroll-based RSI :)

Comment: Gotcha, so you want the numbers that are used to produce the first graph, basically.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

For git repositories I would use a combination of CLOC & git from python, the following script, run in a git repository, would produce the quarterly csv files, these could then be used by any spreadsheet program or plotted with the python csv and matplotlib libraries.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding:utf-8
# Author:  Steve Barnes --<gadgetsteve@hotmail.com>
# Purpose: Create cloc counts across years
# Created: 27/06/14
"""
This python script aims to run cloc multiple times on a git VCS as at quarterly
time intervals.

Usage:
   python histcloc.py start_year [end_year]
"""
import sys
import csv
import os
import subprocess
import datetime

def GetNextQuaterDateStr(startyear, endyear):
    """ Generator for the date strings of each quarter."""
    quaterstartmonth = [1, 3, 6, 9]
    first_year = int(startyear)
    stop_at = int(endyear) + 1
    for year in xrange(first_year, stop_at):
        for month in quaterstartmonth:
            yield '%04d-%02d-01' % (year, month)

def SetAsDate(datstr):
    """
    For a specified repository set it to the state of the trunk on the specified
    date
    """
    commands = ['git', 'checkout',
                "`git rev-list -n 1 --before=\"%s\" master`"% datstr]
    print 'CMD:', ' '.join(commands)
    #result = subprocess.call(commands) # This does'n work for some reason
    result = os.system(' '.join(commands))
    return result

def DoCloc(datsr):
    """ Perform the cloc placing the results in a file specified by datestr."""
    commands = ['perl',
                '~/Downloads/cloc-1.60.pl',  # Replace this to the cloc path
                '.', '--csv', '--out=%s.csv' % datsr]
    result = os.system(' '.join(commands))
    return result

if __name__=='__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print __doc__
        sys.exit(1)
    elif len(sys.argv) < 3:
        sys.argv.append(datetime.datetime.now().year)
    for y in GetNextQuaterDateStr(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]):
        print 'Processing for:', y
        SetAsDate(y)
        DoCloc(y)
```

For SVN I would strongly recommend taking a git clone of the svn repository first and then using the above on that - unless you have a T1 connection it will probably be quicker than multiple svn check out operations.